# Multithreaded pathfinding in Unity C#

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, unity3d

I've tried to implement multithreaded pathfinding in an attempt to increase performance, but if anything, performance seems to actually decrease when I enable multithreading.

Is there anything I should do differently in order to see a performance gain from multithreading?

````
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathRequest
{
    public Vector3          Start;
    public Vector3          Destination;
    public float            MaxRayDistance;
    public List<Vector3>    OutPoints;
    public List<Vector3>    OutDebugSearchList;
    public bool             OutResult;
    public Action           Callback;
}

public class PathFinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    static public PathFinder Get { get; private set; }
    
    [SerializeField] private NavmeshView _navmesh;

    public int MaxThreads = 8;
    public int BufferCountWarning = 200;

    private AStarPool _aStarPool = new AStarPool();
    private Queue<PathRequest> _finishedRequests = new Queue<PathRequest>(100);
    private List<PathRequest> _finishedRequestsBuffer = new List<PathRequest>(100);

    private List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>(20);
    private Queue<PathRequest> _newRequests = new Queue<PathRequest>(100);

    private void Awake()
    {
        //SINGLETON
        if (Get == null)
        {
            Get = this;
        }
        else
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        //ASTAR
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxThreads; ++i)
        {
            _aStarPool.AddItem(new AStar(NeighborStrategy, NeighbourDistanceStrategy, HeuristicStrategy, _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.CenterPoints.Length));
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ExecuteCallbacksOnPathFound();
        UpdateThreads();
    }

    public void RequestPath(PathRequest pr)
    {
        _newRequests.Enqueue(pr);

        //WaitCallback threadwork = (s) => ThreadWork(pr);
        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threadwork);
    }

    public int GetNumNodes()
    {
        return _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.CenterPoints.Length;
    }

    private void StartThread(PathRequest pr)
    {
        ThreadStart threadStart = () => ThreadWork(pr);

        //threadStart.Invoke();

        Thread t = new Thread(threadStart);
        t.Start();
        _threads.Add(t);
    }

    private void ThreadWork(PathRequest pr)
    {
        AStar instance = null;
        lock (_aStarPool)
        {
            instance = _aStarPool.GetItem();
        }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        FindPath(pr, instance);
        sw.Stop();

        lock (_aStarPool)
        {
            _aStarPool.AddItem(instance);
        }

        float distance = 0f;
        if (pr.OutResult)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < pr.OutPoints.Count; ++i)
                distance += (pr.OutPoints[i] - pr.OutPoints[i - 1]).magnitude;
        }
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Path found: {pr.OutResult}, distance: {distance}, with elapsed ms {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}");

        lock (_finishedRequests)
        {
            _finishedRequests.Enqueue(pr);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateThreads()
    {
        for(int i = _threads.Count -1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if(!_threads[i].IsAlive)
            {
                _threads.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        while(_threads.Count < MaxThreads)
        {
            if(_newRequests.Count > 0)
            {
                StartThread(_newRequests.Dequeue());
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(_newRequests.Count > BufferCountWarning)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Warning: over {BufferCountWarning} path requests in queue");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteCallbacksOnPathFound()
    {
        if (_finishedRequests.Count > 0)
        {
            _finishedRequestsBuffer.Clear();
            lock (_finishedRequests)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _finishedRequests.Count; ++i)
                {
                    _finishedRequestsBuffer.Add(_finishedRequests.Dequeue());
                }
            }

            foreach (var request in _finishedRequestsBuffer)
            {
                request.Callback();
            }
        }
    }

    private void NeighborStrategy(int nodeIn, int[] nArr)
    {
        nArr[0] = _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.TriangleConnections[nodeIn * 3];
        nArr[1] = _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.TriangleConnections[nodeIn * 3 + 1];
        nArr[2] = _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.TriangleConnections[nodeIn * 3 + 2];
    }

    private float NeighbourDistanceStrategy(int nodeFrom, int toNeighbour)
    {
        return _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.TriangleConnectionsDistances[nodeFrom * 3 + toNeighbour];
    }

    private float HeuristicStrategy(int nodeFrom, int nodeTo)
    {
        Vector3 posFrom = _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.CenterPoints[nodeFrom];
        Vector3 posTo = _navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.CenterPoints[nodeTo];
        return (posTo - posFrom).magnitude;
    }

    private void FindPath(PathRequest pr, AStar aStar)
    {
        Vector3 navmeshStartPos = default(Vector3);
        Vector3 navmeshEndPos = default(Vector3);
        pr.OutResult = false;

        int startNode = _navmesh.GetClosestPointOnNavmesh_Partitioning(new Ray(pr.Start, Vector3.down), pr.MaxRayDistance, ref navmeshStartPos);
        if (startNode == -1) return;
        int endNode = _navmesh.GetClosestPointOnNavmesh_Partitioning(new Ray(pr.Destination, Vector3.down), pr.MaxRayDistance, ref navmeshEndPos);
        if (endNode == -1) return;

        List<int> nodes = null;

        bool success = false;
        Stopwatch sw = null;

        //sw = new Stopwatch();
        //sw.Start();
        //success = _aStar.OldFindPathNodes(startNode, endNode, ref nodes);
        //sw.Stop();
        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Old AStar ran with {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");

        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        success = aStar.FindPathNodes(startNode, endNode, ref nodes);
        sw.Stop();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"AStar ran with {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");

        if (!success) return;

        if (pr.OutDebugSearchList != null)
        {
            pr.OutDebugSearchList.Clear();
            foreach(int node in nodes)
            {
                pr.OutDebugSearchList.Add(_navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.CenterPoints[node]);
            }
        }

        pr.OutPoints.Clear();
        foreach(int node in nodes)
        {
            pr.OutPoints.Add(_navmesh.NavmeshSO.Navmesh.CenterPoints[node]);
        }
        pr.OutPoints.Add(pr.Destination);

        pr.OutResult = true;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: One tip: `_threads` collection isn't thread-safe, be sure not to damage while using it concurrently.

Comment: @aepot why is it not threadsafe?

Comment: Because `List<T>` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: I would try using Unity's JOBs system for multi-threading, they'll take care of a lot of the scheduling headaches and it'll try to only create as many threads as you need, limiting overhead. If you can write codes within the constraints of "HPC#" (high-performance C#), then you'll get super aggressive compiler optimizations thanks to Unity's BURST compiler that will produce faster code than anything you could write with plain old C# multi-threading land. For any more detailed feedback, we'll probably need more context.